python selenium need help in locating username and password
i am new to selenium . i am trying to scrape financial data on tradingview.
i am trying to log into https://www.tradingview.com/accounts/signin/ . i understand that i am facing a timeout issue right now, is there any way to fix this? thank you to anybody helping. much appreciated.
however, i am facing alot of errors with logging in. the error i am facing is
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-7f9f0236fad7> in <cell line: 24>()
     22 # Login process (replace with your email and password)
     23 # Locate the email/username field using the 'id' or 'name' attribute
---> 24 email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_username")))
     25 email_field.send_keys("tom@gmail.com")  # Replace with your email
     26 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
    103                 break
    104             time.sleep(self._poll)
--> 105         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    106 
    107     def until_not(self, method: Callable[[D], T], message: str = "") -> Union[T, 

Literal[True]]:
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5677df5f58fa <unknown>
#1 0x5677df106d20 <unknown>
#2 0x5677df155a66 <unknown>
#3 0x5677df155d01 <unknown>

this is my code over here.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Set up Selenium WebDriver for Colab
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Needed for Colab
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  # Overcome resource limitations
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Disable GPU for compatibility
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')  # Set a default window size
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Example: Open the TradingView login page
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/accounts/signin/")

# Wait for the login page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# Login process (replace with your email and password)
# Locate the email/username field using the 'id' or 'name' attribute
email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_username")))  
email_field.send_keys("tom@gmail.com")  # Replace with your email

# Locate the password field using the 'id' or 'name' attribute
password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_password")
password_field.send_keys("Fs5u+exxxx1")  # Replace with your password

# Locate and click the login button
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()

# Wait for login to complete (adjust sleep time as necessary)
time.sleep(5)

if "Sign In" in driver.page_source:
    print("Login failed. Check your credentials.")
else:
    print("Login successful!")

# Navigate to a chart page (e.g., btc chart)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/kvfFlBvq/?symbol=INDEX%3ABTCUSD")
time.sleep(5)

# Example: Extract data from a visible container
try:
    data_container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "container")
    print("Extracted Data:")
    print(data_container.text)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to extract data:", e)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()


To locate the login form on the sign-in page, it is necessary to click the "Email" button first in order to proceed with submitting the login form.
I have included the following two lines in the script to accomplish this.
email_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='Email']")
email_button.click()

The login form does not contain a button of type "submit." Instead, there is only a button without a specified type. To perform the login action, I used the span text "Sign in" to identify and click the appropriate button.
Your code:
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")

Updated code by me:
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sign in']")

The login process was successful. However, after logging in, the system is unable to locate any container elements.
I trust you will be able to address this issue.
The complete code, with corrections applied, is presented below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Set up Selenium WebDriver for Colab
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Needed for Colab
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  # Overcome resource limitations
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Disable GPU for compatibility
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')  # Set a default window size
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Example: Open the TradingView login page
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/accounts/signin/")

# Wait for the login page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# newly added by me
email_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='Email']")
email_button.click()

# Login process (replace with your email and password)
# Locate the email/username field using the 'id' or 'name' attribute
email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_username")))  
email_field.send_keys("tom@gmail.com")  # Replace with your email

# Locate the password field using the 'id' or 'name' attribute
password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_password")
password_field.send_keys("Fs5u+exxxx1")  # Replace with your password

# Locate and click the login button
# Edited by me
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sign in']")
login_button.click()

# Wait for login to complete (adjust sleep time as necessary)
time.sleep(5)

if "Sign In" in driver.page_source:
    print("Login failed. Check your credentials.")
else:
    print("Login successful!")

# Navigate to a chart page (e.g., btc chart)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/kvfFlBvq/?    symbol=INDEX%3ABTCUSD")
time.sleep(5)

# Example: Extract data from a visible container
try:
    data_container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "container")
    print("Extracted Data:")
    print(data_container.text)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to extract data:", e)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()


Thank you for your help. i believe that removing the line 'login_button.click()' helps with running the code. there was an error with the login click button. Nevertheless, thank you for your help sir. :)
